# Simple Task for understanding Multithreading in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a few questions about threads in java.

For better understanding I am trying to solve some simple tasks with threads. I have a method which gets an `int value` and an `int tCount` and return a `long result`. What it should do is just counting, starting from one and adding each to `result`. Now the `tCount` variable tells me with how many threads I should do it. Example:

`myMethod(10, 1)` should calculate: `1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 + 9 + 10` in a single thread and return the `long result`.

`myMethod(10, 2)` should calculate the same but lets say like this:

- `thread1` calculates `1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9`
- `thread2` calculates `2 + 4 + 6 + 8 + 10`

in the end the two results should be added to the `long result` and `result` should be returned.

When I tried to implement it I had different approaches. For example with anonymous class (always had problems with variables that should be effectively final) but nothing got even close to working.

What are your ideas?

- Create an extra `class` `extends Thread` or implementing `Runnable`?
- How would you create the amount of Threads which are given to your method?
- Where would you implement which Variable so you can access it when you need it?
- And what about the Thread Management? The Variable result should not be used by the different Threads simultaneously right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The first thing that comes to my mind are `CompletableFuture`s. You can read about them [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture).

Comment: Please post some of the code you've tried.

Comment: `extends Thread` vs. `implements Runnable` is a question that has been asked and answered many times on this site. Use the search feature to find the answers.

Comment: Re, "Where would you implement which Variable so you can access it when you need it?" If that's something you need help with, then I would advise you to spend more time learning the Java language, and learning about object oriented design before you dive in to learning about threads. Threads are a challenging subject. No point in handicapping yourself by trying to understand threads while writing code in a language that you do not fully understand.

Answer (score 0):

you can create two threads,One of the threads executes and enters a wait state，Then wake up another thread,The other one goes into a wait state after execution, then wakes up another thread.Execute alternately like this.